# Batch File to move filenames given from a .txt or .xls to user specific directory

Tags: variables, batch-file, xlsx

Using the command `move`, but instead of using "user" input I want this to be done by reading the lines out of an .txt or .xls or any other file where I can put in variables more or less.

So instead of asking for user input like:

```
SET /P filename=Enter the file which should be moved:
move %filename%.* \directoryX
```

I want to set a variable which is a loop by reading a .txt or .xls. Each row contain 1 specific filename.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch file to copy files from a file contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551543/batch-file-to-copy-files-from-a-file-contents)

Answer (score 1):

Assume you've made the following entries in list.list:

```
file1.txt
file2.xls
file3.jpg
```

The following batch script would move those files to the temp directory:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "list.list"') do move "%%i" "c:\temp"
```

If you want to test things out, put an `echo` in there like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "list.list"') do echo move "%%i" "c:\temp"
```